# How to get sum(Net_weight) in to query result from MySQL and save in to MSSQL with ID

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have Query Like `SELECT SUM(Length) FROM tbl_test WHERE ID = @ID and date= @date` I am assigning Date into the string

```
MysqlConnection con = new mysqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnectionString"].ToString());
mySqlCommand read_command = new mySqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Length) FROM tbl_test ID =@ID and date=@date", con);
        read_command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = yesterday ;
        mySqlDataReader read_rd;
        string SUM ;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            read_rd = read_command.ExecuteReader();
            if (read_pass_rd.HasRows)
            {
                while (read_rd.Read())
                {
                    SUM = read_rd.GetString(0);
                }
            }
            read_rd.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
```

When running this query I am getting query result using My SQL.
Now the problem is I need to save query result Sum(length) to save MSSQL table with id and Yesterday date. How to save into MS SQL Table because this windows service application how to save ID and Yesterday Date.

Comment: what is the issue in saving ID and yesterday's date?

Comment: I need a save query result with id and date

Answer (score 0):

You can create a connection of MSSql similar to MySQL. And pass `Id`, `Sum`, and `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)` to insert query of MS SQL.